# How to make a class to be clicked when new page load?

Tags: jquery

I have a class name "searchIcon", and i wrote a click function to that class.

In HTML

```
     <div class="searchIcon">Icon</div>
```

In Js file

```
  $(".searchIcon").click(function(){
   //class function
  });
```

I want this function should be clicked at time of page load.

maximum i need it in jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `.click()` or `.trigger('click')` right after you bind the event.

```
$(function() {
    $(".searchIcon").click(function(){
        //class funstion
    }).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in document.ready function :-

> $(".searchIcon").trigger('click');

```
$(function() {
    $(".searchIcon").click(function(){

    });
    $(".searchIcon").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the click handler directly call a function and then on page load call that same function ([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cteegarden/rB9Us/3/)):

```
$(".searchIcon").click(function(){
   //class function
    clickFunction();
});

var clickFunction = function(){
      alert("clicked!");  
};

clickFunction();
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code requires a click trigger at page load:

```
$(function(){ // ready handler
    $(".searchIcon").click(function(){
       //class function
    });
    $(".searchIcon").click(); // this fires when doc gets ready
});
```